# Let $G:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $G(x)=\|F(x)\|^2$. Prove $G$ is a differentiable function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m $ be a differentiable function in inner points $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $G:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $G(x)=\|F(x)\|^2$.

Prove $G$  is a differentiable function.

I have to show that $\frac{\|G(x+\delta x)-G(x)-DG|_x(\delta x)\|}{\|x+\delta x\|}=0$

My attempt:

$\frac{\|G(x+\delta x)-G(x)-DG|_x(\delta x)\|}{\|x+\delta x\|}=\frac{\|\|F(x+\delta x)\|^2-\|F(x)\|^2-D(\|F\|^2)|_x(\delta x)\|}{\|x+\delta x\|}=\frac{\|(\|F(x+\delta x)\|-\|F(x)\|)(\|F(x+\delta x)\|+\|F(x)\|)-D(\|F\|^2)|_x(\delta x)\|}{\|x+\delta x\|}$

I get stuck , any help is appreciate.

Comment: What is your definition of $\|F(x)\|^{2}$, is it equal to $\langle F(x),F(x)\rangle=F^{1}F^{1}+\dots+F^{m}F^{m}$?

Comment: If so, we can prove it by definition. $\langle F(x+\Delta x),F(x+\Delta x)\rangle-\langle F(x),F(x)\rangle=\langle F(x+\Delta x),F(x+\Delta x)\rangle-\langle F(x+\Delta x),F(x)\rangle+\langle F(x+\Delta x),F(x)\rangle-\langle F(x),F(x)\rangle$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $N(x)=\|x\|^2$. Then $N\bigl((x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\bigr)=x_1^{\,2}+x_2^{\,2}+\cdots+x_n^{\,2}$, and therefore $N$ is differentiable. So, since $G=N\circ F$, $G$ is differentiable.